# Can I connect Amazon RDS PostgreSQL with Active Directory AD or AD Connector?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want configure my Amazon RDS PostgreSQL with a connection to AD or similar.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL Supports User Authentication with Kerberos and Microsoft Active Directory
Posted On: Oct 29, 2019

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-supports-user-authentication-with-kerberos-and-microsoft-active-directory/?nc1=h_ls

Thank you!